# DT.strptime interpreting %d wrong

Tags: python, error-handling, decimal, strptime

I have:

```
import datetime as DT

for i in range(len(data)):
    dates[i]=str(DT.datetime.strptime("%s-%s-%s" %(data[i][0][2],data[i][0][0],data[i][0][1]),"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

where `(data[i][0][2],data[i][0][0],data[i][0][1])` gives a year, month, and date, respectively.

The problem is that I am getting `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1885-05-02 00:00:00` because it seems to be interpreting %d as a decimal instead of as a day.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as DT

for day in data:
    date=DT.datetime.strptime(day, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping to conclusions about the `%d` a bit early. First - I don't see the float conversion in this code. Second - the string in the error includes time, but you say it should be year, month, day only. Please check what you're really providing. Also, you can construct the string yourself if you already have the values - no need to first construct the string and then parse it again and get string out of it...

This should be do the same:

```
for i, parts in enumerate(data):
    dates[i] = "%s-%02i-%02i 00:00:00" % (parts[0][2], int(parts[0][0]), int(parts[0][1]))
```

(you can drop the int cast if they're already ints)

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why it has the time there.  My data only has dates  (it's daily closing stock values) and obviously my code only lists YMD.